# PHP Array Building to avoid MAX RAM exceeded

Tags: php, arrays, ram

I am creating an array of successful URLs and parsing a file stored in a temporary directory. This is fine until the array gets huge and eventually causes the max ram to exceed. What would be a good solution on handling this process so it can handle this regardless of the volume of URLs in a CSV?

```
if($fh = fopen( ($fileName) ? $fileName : $this->file->getTempName() , 'r'))
{
     // iterate through all lines of file
     while($line = fgetcsv($fh, self::MAX_READ, self::DELIMITER)){

     $this->addUrl(array(
        self::SOURCE => $line[self::FROM_COLUMN],
        self::DESTINATION => $line[self::TO_COLUMN],
        self::EXPIRY_TIME => $line[self::DATE_COLUMN]
     ));

     }

     fclose($fh);
}

public function addUrl( $url)
{
    $this->urls[] = $url;
}
```

In my processor class:

```
foreach($urls as $entry)
{
   // new url instance
   $url= new Url();
   $url->source = $entry[CSV::SOURCE];
   $url->destination= $entry[CSV::DESTINATION];
   $url->save();
```

}

Comment: It is unclear what the given code does. You have show definition of `addUrl()` method at least

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question but it might be a XY Problem, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem : Why are you parsing all that data from a file to an array?

Comment: Do you *need* all these URLs in memory at once? Could you not process them one by one as you read them and then discard each after you're done with it? Storing them all in an array is not the end goal, I presume?

Comment: I use this array to then loop through and create a new active record for each.

Comment: And can't you create a new active record for each right after you have read the line from CSV, without storing it in an array first?

Comment: Please tell us more about this "active record". What does it do for you, what problem does it solve?

Comment: I am using Yii active record. I have updated question